# How to update MySQL database from Outlook Express?

Tags: mysql, vba, outlook

I noticed in outlook express that there is a macros function and so I want to play with it! Unfortanetly, I have not programmed in VB for about 5 years.

I get a lot of mailer daemons from clients and employees to my email system which someone has to go through and update our MySQL database to void the email manually.

So, I want to know if it is possible to take the emails from the mailer daemons and simply update a MySQL database with a macros? Resources or examples please?

I'm sure it is simple but my google searches come back with little help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some rough notes.

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim sCon As String
Dim sSQL As String
Dim oNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim oItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

sCon = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=MyDB;" _
& "User=UName;Password=PWord;Option=3;"

cn.Open sCon

Set oNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set oFolder = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

For Each oItem In oFolder.Items
    If Left(oItem.Sender, 13) = "MAILER-DAEMON" Then
        sSQL = "INSERT INTO TestTable (data) VALUES ('" & oItem.Sender & "')"
        cn.Execute sSQL
    End If
Next
```

See also: http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=62
http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql

Comment: I understand the example pretty well but I looked at the variable sCon and wondered what that was about. I read your resources and it makes perfect sense to me now but I can't seem to set the correct information for sCon with the Driver option.

Comment: Have you got drivers (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.1.html) ? Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

These tutorial/post here explain well how to event handle (first link for Mail event; second link for Calendar event):

https://www.slipstick.com/developer/itemadd-macro/

[VBA how to event handle ItemAdd & ItemChange both (for Outlook 2016 Calendar)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73588311/vba-how-to-event-handle-itemadd-itemchange-both-for-outlook-2016-calendar)

and this post here explains well how to use VBA to connect with MySQL :

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/how-vba-connect-mysql-database-and-run-a-simple-query.1054774/

Combine the above, with minor modifications you should be able to achieve what you wanted.

Make sure you have the ODBC driver whose download link is as Fionnuala supplied.