# VBA how to event handle ItemAdd & ItemChange both (for Outlook 2016 Calendar)?

Tags: vba, outlook

I use the offline version of Microsoft Outlook 2016 Calendar on Windows 10 (64 bit).

GOAL:

When a new appointment is created, OR, when an existing appointment is modified, I would like a Msg box to pop up and display the GlobalAppointmentID of the appointment.

WHAT I HAVE TRIED SO FAR:

Diane Poremsky wrote a good [article](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/itemadd-macro/) explaning how to event handle ItemAdd for Mail. I adopted it for Calendar and it worked. This code shown below will display the GlobalAppointmentID as a popup Msg whenever a new appointment is created in Calendar. It works for ItemAdd (without ItemChange):

```
Option Explicit
Private objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Private WithEvents objItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
 
Dim objWatchFolder As Outlook.Folder
Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

'Set the folder and items to watch:
Set objWatchFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
Set objItems = objWatchFolder.Items

Set objWatchFolder = Nothing
End Sub



Private Sub objItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

' Your code goes here
' MsgBox "Message subject: " & Item.Subject & vbCrLf & "Message sender: " & Item.SenderName & " (" & Item.SenderEmailAddress & ")"
' https://www.slipstick.com/developer/itemadd-macro

 MsgBox "*** PROPERTIES of olFolderCalendar ***" & vbNewLine & _
        "Subject: " & Item.Subject & vbNewLine & _
        "Start: " & Item.Start & vbNewLine & _
        "End: " & Item.End & vbNewLine & _
        "Duration: " & Item.Duration & vbNewLine & _
        "Location: " & Item.Location & vbNewLine & _
        "Body: " & Item.Body & vbNewLine & _
        "Global Appointment ID: " & Item.GlobalAppointmentID
        
Set Item = Nothing
End Sub
```

This following code shown below will display a popup Msg of the GlobalAppointmentID, whenever an existing appointment is modified. It works for ItemChange (without ItemAdd):

```
Option Explicit
Private objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Private WithEvents objItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
 
Dim objWatchFolder As Outlook.Folder
Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

'Set the folder and items to watch:
Set objWatchFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
Set objItems = objWatchFolder.Items

Set objWatchFolder = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub objItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)

 MsgBox "*** PROPERTIES of olFolderCalendar ***" & vbNewLine & _
        "Global Appointment ID: " & Item.GlobalAppointmentID
        
Set Item = Nothing
End Sub
```

However, when I combined both ItemAdd and ItemChange in the same VBA code, neither of them works.
This code shown below does not work for ItemAdd and does not work for ItemChange:

```
Option Explicit
Private objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Private WithEvents objItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
 
Dim objWatchFolder As Outlook.Folder
Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

'Set the folder and items to watch:
Set objWatchFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
Set objItems = objWatchFolder.Items

Set objWatchFolder = Nothing
End Sub



Private Sub objItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    
 MsgBox "*** PROPERTIES of olFolderCalendar ***" & vbNewLine & _
        "Subject: " & Item.Subject & vbNewLine & _
        "Start: " & Item.Start & vbNewLine & _
        "End: " & Item.End & vbNewLine & _
        "Duration: " & Item.Duration & vbNewLine & _
        "Location: " & Item.Location & vbNewLine & _
        "Body: " & Item.Body & vbNewLine & _
        "Global Appointment ID: " & Item.GlobalAppointmentID
        
Set Item = Nothing
End Sub




Private Sub objItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)

 MsgBox "*** PROPERTIES of olFolderCalendar ***" & vbNewLine & _
        "Global Appointment ID: " & Item.GlobalAppointmentID
        
Set Item = Nothing
End Sub
```

QUESTION:

How should I correct the code such that both ItemAdd and ItemChange work please? In other words whenever a new appointment is added or an existing appointment is modified, a popup Msg will show the appointment's GlobalAppointmentID.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

The following code captures both ItemAdd and ItemChange if any one is interested.

I made a separate WithEvents
and a separate Set ObjItems

Then it worked.

```
Option Explicit
Private objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Private WithEvents objItems As Outlook.Items
Private WithEvents objItems2 As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
 
Dim objWatchFolder As Outlook.Folder
Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

'Set the folder and items to watch:
Set objWatchFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
Set objItems = objWatchFolder.Items
Set objItems2 = objWatchFolder.Items

Set objWatchFolder = Nothing
End Sub



Private Sub objItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

' Your code goes here
' MsgBox "Message subject: " & Item.Subject & vbCrLf & "Message sender: " & Item.SenderName & " (" & Item.SenderEmailAddress & ")"
' https://www.slipstick.com/developer/itemadd-macro

 MsgBox "*** PROPERTIES of olFolderCalendar ***" & vbNewLine & _
        "Subject: " & Item.Subject & vbNewLine & _
        "Start: " & Item.Start & vbNewLine & _
        "End: " & Item.End & vbNewLine & _
        "Duration: " & Item.Duration & vbNewLine & _
        "Location: " & Item.Location & vbNewLine & _
        "Body: " & Item.Body & vbNewLine & _
        "Global Appointment ID: " & Item.GlobalAppointmentID
        
Set Item = Nothing
End Sub




Private Sub objItems2_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)

 MsgBox "*** PROPERTIES of olFolderCalendar ***" & vbNewLine & _
        "Subject: " & Item.Subject & vbNewLine & _
        "Start: " & Item.Start & vbNewLine & _
        "End: " & Item.End & vbNewLine & _
        "Duration: " & Item.Duration & vbNewLine & _
        "Location: " & Item.Location & vbNewLine & _
        "Body: " & Item.Body & vbNewLine & _
        "Global Appointment ID: " & Item.GlobalAppointmentID
        
Set Item = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no need to keep instances of the same collection to be able to handle events.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set items passed as parameters to `Nothing` in the event handlers:

```
Set Item = Nothing
```

Items that are passed as parameters are released by the caller (Outlook in your case).

There is no need to keep two instances of the `Items` class in the code to be able to handle events. Try to not release items passed as parameters first.

Comment: Hi Euege, currently I am doing Set objItems = objWatchFolder.Items and 
Set objItems2 = objWatchFolder.Items .  It seems a little redundant. Do you mean I only need one of them , and still be able to capture both ItemAdd and ItemChange? If so, how would you modify my code exactly please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: The problem is in the `Set Item = Nothing` statements. You have already listed a valid code with a single `Items` instance.